# CSS HTML background image displaying over pop-up menu

Tags: html, css

I placed a background image in a class. Now when I click the menu, and it transitions, it displays behind the background image. Is there a way to make the background image less specific? or is there anything else i should be doing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you are talking about, but if I understand you correctly, then set a background for the menu, and your background image will not show through under your menu.

Comment: But it will be better if you show your code here.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] demonstrating the issue. We are left to guess work and voodoo without an example of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Add z-index css property to your tag.

```
.back-img {
    z-index: 1000; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had that problem before and I tried this. It worked.

```
.dropdown-content {
  z-index: 1000;
}
```

Pop-up menu has dropdown-content class.